# setSupportActionBar cannot be applied(android.widget.Toolbar) error

Tags: java, android-studio

whati need to do?
[activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGW5U.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quAzr.png)

[toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM9yl.png)

[toolberinactivityxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BumRW.png)

Comment: Please enter your code as text instead of an image, same with your error report. That way we can help you faster. Thank you.

Comment: as @THess mentioned, you need to put some effort into your question. read [ask] and preferably provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have imported the wrong toolbar in the activity.

You used `androidX.toolbar` in xml and imported `android.toolbar`. Try to import the relevant toolbar in the activity or press ctrl+shift+O to optimize imports.